# Integrate Mathjax and generate PDF

Tags: 6, theming, files

Am working on the site with Mathematical content(Drupal 6.18).
Have success fully integrated Mathjax for representing mathematical equations. But have an problem to generate PDF of same content.

The issue is that Mathjax Processes the Equations after page is loaded and am using the [Print,pdf](http://drupal.org/project/print) module. While PDF generation, content is pull from the database which is not mathjax Processed. Hence scrambled data!!!

Is there anyway I can preprocess the content so that the PDF is generated exactly as shown on the web.

I know there are tools to convert HTML to PDF like wkhtmltopdf but any help doing this with Drupal core will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out all the possible options for implementing mathematical equations, and considering the requirement to create PDF, I got to the conclusion that the only way to do this is using a CKeditor plugin.

There is the fmath plugin, and I found a useful link: [Configuration steps](http://mathmlflash.blogspot.in/2011/01/setup-for-drupal-ckeditor-and-fmath.html).

As JavaScript is loaded after page load, it was very difficult to generate PDF on the fly.

Comment: One last piece of the puzzle, server side image generation code can be configured by following these configuration steps: http://www.fmath.info/plugins/drupal/doc.jsp (Step 3 for Drupal 6)